# How can I get the cell's color in QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to know the color of cell's background. What the function can make it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```cpp
auto item = myTableWidget->itemAt(0, 0); // adapt that to the cell you want
auto color = item->background().color();
```

By the way, I don't want to be an asshole but that took me literally 10 seconds reading [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidgetitem.html#background)

Qt modules (expecially Core and Widgets) are very well documented, it's really worth spending some time searching through it, you'll find answer way faster than waiting for a random guy to answer on stack overflow.

Comment: thanks a lot. i just didnt know that i can use .color()